# 'Observable<HttpEvent<DeviceList>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<DeviceList>

Tags: angular, typescript

```
// GET DEVICES LIST
getDevices(): Observable < DeviceList > {
  this.setToken();
  return this.http.get<DeviceList>(this.api_url + '/devices', this.httpOptions1)
    .retry(2);
}
```

I Don't Know what to do for this scenario, I have created the model and am trying to get the `devicelist` so am adding the model to the `api.service` but am getting this error`

> ```
> ERROR in src/app/services/api.service.ts(86,9): error TS2322:
>   Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<DeviceList>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<DeviceList>'.
>   Type 'HttpEvent<DeviceList>' is not assignable to type 'DeviceList'.
>   Type 'HttpProgressEvent' is not assignable to type 'DeviceList'.
>   Property 'device_family' is missing in type 'HttpProgressEvent'.
> ```

Comment: What's the version of Angular and Rxjs you're using?

Comment: Angular version 7

Comment: what is `httpOptions1`?

Answer (score 0):

You're using Angular 7 which uses Rxjs 6.3

The syntax for adding operators is like this:

```
getDevices(): Observable<DeviceList> {
  this.setToken();
  return this.http.get<DeviceList>(this.api_url + '/devices', this.httpOptions1)
    .pipe(
      retry(2)
    );
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/retry-operator-syntax-in-rxjs-6-3-and-angular-7?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: ERROR in src/app/services/api.service.ts(88,13): error TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'......error @ retry(2)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to fork my stackblitz, implement your case and then share your stackblitz with me so that I could have a look?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/retry-operator-syntax-in-rxjs-6-3-and-angular-7-v7inqo

Comment: @pradeepM, your implementation lacks the api.service.ts and some other information like what is `httpOptions1` what would `setToken` do and things of that sort. Please add those details. I've updated my sample stackblitz though and it should give you a pretty good idea as to what's wrong with your implementation.